# Contact Sync Adapter showing "Phone only, unsynced contact"

Tags: android, synchronization

I've already created custom account using Authenticator Service & my account does get created successfully.This is how I'm adding contact:

```
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.account_type))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.mime_type))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.
            newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, id)
            .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()
    );
    Log.e(TAG, "contact added: " + name + ", " + number);

    try {
        resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Phone's contacts is showing this : "Phone only, unsynced contact". I can't figure it out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My mistake was that I defined wrong contentAuthority for my sync adapter inside xml file.

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.example.syncadapter.provider"
    android:accountType="com.example.account"
    android:userVisible="true"/>
```

while required value was

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.example.account"
    android:userVisible="true"/>
```